# MAMP: How to install Memcached?

Tags: memcached, mamp

I have tried to install memcached in MAMP - Snow Leopard 10.6.2 using this tutorial:

[Setup a Memcached-Enabled MAMP Sandbox Environment](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/setup-memcached-mamp-sandbox-environment)

I finished with no errors the first to the last step: **Bonus Section: Start and Stop Memcache with MAMP**

After that I restarted my MAMP widget in the dashboard and checked by phpinfo but the memcached extension is not there.

Do you guys successfully installed memcached in your MAMP or do you know any other way on how to make it work?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Should be moved to serverfault.com

Comment: Oh.Ok I will post my question there :) Thanks

Comment: Bump. I am still stuck to this question. Hoping that anyone here can help me with my problem. Right now I am using Windows 7 but my drupal project is not running there and gets an apache error 'The connection was reset'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Already solved it. Posting my answer to my question for future reference :)

How to install memcache php extension in MAMP:

follow this tutorial:
http://www.lullabot.com/articles/setup-memcached-mamp-sandbox-environment

http://marc.info/?l=php-general&m=123849727830637&w=2

download this correct memcache.so
http://daleenterprise.com/download/memcache.so

Install Xcode Tools from your Mac OS X DVD or download it from Apple Developer Connection to install the GNU Compiler Collection (gcc).

install first the xcode tools in the mac os x dvd then download and install the second one.
filename of installer:  xcode321_10m2003_developerdvd.dmg

Comment: Isn't the question asking for memcached.so ?

Answer (score 11):

Pecl Memcached library for MAMP which is always up to date.

Here is the github repo: https://github.com/majksner/php-memcached-mamp

Comment: This is the most up to date answer as it contains several versions for most current PHP versions. The currently accepted answer doesn't.

Comment: It is 2015 and majksner/php-memcached-mamp is still the best resource for configuring MAMP and Memcached.

Answer (score 4):

In the latest MAMP for mac I had to add the following to PHP.ini (note also, it is NOT the PHP.ini in the /conf directory, it is in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.7/conf.php.ini, look at the output of phpinfo() to see which PHP.ini is active)

```
extension=igbinary.so
extension=memcached.so
```

Answer (score 2):

MAMP 4 does come with memcached. In fact you will need to enable two extensions in `php.ini`. This is important, otherwise memcached won't load:

```
extension=msgpack.so
extension=memcached.so
```

memcached.so depends on mghpack.so

Comment: Thank you, saved my day! Kept trying to add just memcached.so for a while :O

Comment: Some solutions I've read included having to compile PHP's source code(!!!). Yours is a lot easier hehehe :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note for anyone in need: MAMP 4 now ships with memcached extension, but it's not enabled by default. One needs to edit php.ini template for PHP versions being used and uncomment memcached.so

Comment: Uncommenting memcached.so only didn't do the trick for me, I had also do add msgpack.so, like @minnur pointed out on the answer above.

Comment: or:

extension=igbinary.so

extension=memcached.so